Reapply local changes on top of "upstream" library without repo
I'm working on a Unity project and I have a few libraries/packages my project depends on. I don't have the repo to any of the upstream libraries, I'll just get a package with all the new source code. If I had access to the library's repo this would be easy, but I do not unfortunately.
I've needed to make a few local changes in some of the libraries, nothing very extensive. But whenever I update the library I need to make those changes again.
Are there any git workflows for handling things like this? I'm not expecting my changes to magically merge each time. But I think it would be easier if I could update the library, run some commands to apply my changes, eyeball the diffs, and go from there.
Thanks!
The best I could come up with is a git patch, then applying the patch after the library is updated. But that feels kinda like a clunky solution to me.

Setup a repo of your own for each library.... Keep in master/main the library code without modifications.... Create a branch from it for your adjustments.... Then when you want to update the library from upstream, you replace the whole content of the main branch and add this new content and commit... Then go to your private branch and merge or rebase on the branch with the upstream code.

Ok, that solution came to mind but I was hoping there'd be a slightly cleaner workflow. But I think this should help me needed to repeatedly make the same changes over, especially as they get more complex.
Thanks!
